How to make sin function go through a specific point AFTER having reached a maximum
I am using a sin graph to represent a projectile going through a certain point, and I need said projectile to reach a maximum before reaching the point.
The function looks something like this:
2sin(bx)+2 = y
I need this function to go through the point (4.55, 3.048), but it MUST reach a maximum beforehand.
I was able to use desmos graphing calculator to reach my value of b, which is .5692, but I need math to back it up.
I decided to turn the function "sinx" into a polynomial using the Mclauren sequence in order to get possible values for b. The function "sinx" had been turned into:
x-((x^{3})/6)+((x^{5})/120)....
I decided to only use the first three terms for this problem to save time. I plugged in "bx" from the original function in for "x" on the mclauren sequence.
I then plugged this into my original equation of sinx which turned into:
2((bx)-(((bx)^{3})/6)+(((bx)^{5})/120)+2 = y
I then plugged in the point I wanted to get to in my original equation: (4.55, 3.048) for x and y respectively.
2((4.55b)-(((4.55b)^{3})/6)+(((4.55b)^{5})/120)+2 = y
which then simplifies to:
16.25083711x^{5}-15.69939583x^{3}+4.55x-.524
The possible values should theoretically be on the x axis of the above polynomial when graphed:
Two points on the graph are (.121217,0) and (.690382,0)
Something I noticed was that, although I didn't get my intended value of .5692, when I subtract the x value of the first point from the second, I get .569155, which is rather close to my answer. My question ultimately is:
Is this just a massive coincidence, or is there a reason for this?

Yes, there is a reason behind this, while using maclaurin series at the place of sinx, you'll get an error. Because it's a series of infinite terms, and you are using only three terms that's why you got the nearby value rather than a correct one.
Coming to your question, if you want your function reaches maximum beforehand, then use the fact that maximum value of sinx is 1 at x=π/2.
Here it's sin(bx), so at bx=π/2,sin is maximum.I think now you can proceed.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

So your equation is:
$$2\sin(bx)+2 = y$$
... and it must pass trough the point $(4.55, 3.048)$.
This means that $3.048 = 2 + 2 \sin (b \cdot 4.55)$.
From there you can derive the value of $b$ ($b=\arcsin{\left(\frac{3.048 - 2}{2}\right)}/4.55$). No need for series expansion.
